# Is it possible to textchanged event to occur only when textBox is focused?

Tags: c#, events, textbox, textchanged

I have method like this.

```
    public void CheckEmployee()
    {
            ConnectionStringSettings myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LibrarySystem.Properties.Settings.LibraryConnectionString"];
            using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
            {
                myDatabaseConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee where EmployeeID = '" + EmployeeIDtextBox.Text + "' ", myDatabaseConnection))
                using (SqlDataReader sqlreader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    if (sqlreader.Read())
                    {
                        string EmployeeID = sqlreader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                        string Name = sqlreader.GetString(1);
                        string Address = sqlreader.GetString(2);

                        EmployeeIDtextBox.Text = EmployeeID;
                        NametextBox.Text = Name;
                        AddresstextBox.Text = Address;
                    }
                }
            }
     }
```

And I have to write a code something like this.

```
private void EmployeeIDtextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBook();
    NametextBox.Clear();
    AddresstextBox.Clear();
}

private void NametextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBook();
    EmployeetextBox.Clear();
    AddresstextBox.Clear();
}
```

The problem is NametextBox_TextChanged triggers also when i input in EmployeeIDtextBox because the method gets a value from database and display it NametextBox.

Is it possible for NametextBox_TextChanged to occur only when NametextBox is focused? And vice versa.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, try simply ignoring the `TextChanged` event if `NametextBox` is not focused - something like this:

```
private void NametextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NametextBox.IsFocused)
    {
        CheckBook();
        EmployeetextBox.Clear();
        AddresstextBox.Clear();
    }
}
```